# Amazon SES with SNS bounce reports. One or multiple addresses in a single report?

Tags: php, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm writing a PHP script to be an Amazon SNS end point for Amazon SES bounce/complain notifications.

I need to know if SNS sends one notification per each email address bouncing, or if it will collect and send one notification with multiple addresses bounced. I cant find an answer to this on Amazon docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior does not appear to be constrained one way or the other.

`complainedRecipients` and `bouncedRecipients` are lists, so it definitely *can* be multiple recipients per notification, but whether multiple destination ISPs are involved, and the timing of the responses from the destination ISPs appears to determine how many recipients might be included in one notification.  You could see multiple notifications for one message, or just one notification for multiple recipients.

Also, worth noting, the complaint notification recipients are sometimes determined by a best-effort guess, since complaint reports may be ambiguous and SES will try to heuristically guess, in that case:

> Since most ISPs redact the email address of the recipient who submitted the complaint from their complaint notification, this list contains information about recipients who might have sent the complaint, based on the recipients of the original message and the ISP from which we received the complaint.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html